# select on sub query peewee

Tags: subquery, peewee

I am wondering if I can do select() on sub_query.
I am able to do join sub_query with any peewee.Model. But when I wrote a sub_query and I wanted to just group by with one of the column

`e.g. sub_query.select(sub_query.c.column_1, fn.COUNT(sub_query.c.column2)alias('col2_count')).group_by(sub_query.c.column_1)`

query was not nested and was giving SQL syntax error.

(Can't reveal the code)
(I have done alias() on sub_query)

**Edit**

Example:

```
class Product(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = CharField()
    created_date = DateField()


class Part(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    product = ForeignKeyField(Product)
    name = CharField()


class ProductError(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    product = ForeignKeyField(Product)
    note = CharField()

class PartError(Model):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    part = ForeignKeyField(Part)
    error = ForeignKeyField(ErrorMaster)
```

Here Product can have general error and 
parts can have specific error which are predefined in ErrorMaster

I just want to know count of product which have errors against total products date wise. (error is product error or error in any part)

So sub_query is something like

```
sub_q = Product.select(
                Product.created_date,
                Product.id.alias('product_id'),
                fn.IF(# checks if product has error
                    ProductError.is_null(True),  if no product error check part error
                    fn.IF(fn.COUNT(PartError.id) == 0, 0, 1),  # checks if error count > 0 then there is error in part
                    1
                ).alias('is_error')
            ).join(Part, on=Product.id == Part.product)
            .join(ProductError, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=Product.id == ProductError.product)
            .join(PartError, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=PartError.part == Part.id)
            .where(Product.created_date.between(from_date, to_date))
            .group_by(Product.id).alias('some_alias')
# below does not work but I can do this in sql
query = sub_q.select(sub_q.c.created_date,
                 fn.COUNT(sub_q.c.product_id).alias('total_products'),
        fn.SUM(sub_q.c.is_error).alias('product_with_errors'))
             .group_by(sub_q.c.created_date)
```

Comment: Can you give a more practical example?

Comment: @coleifer I have added example similar to my scenario. Ignore if any brace is missing in query somewhere as I directly coded this in simple text editor